# How to add tooltip in MudDataGrid?

Tags: datagrid, mudblazor

I have a MudDataGrid and I want to display a tooltip for column header when I hover over it.
Could anyone guide me how to achieve it.
Thanks in advance for your answer.

I tried to display tooltip for MudDataGrid column Header when anyone hover over it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TemplateColumn` to create custom templates for *Header*,*Footer* and *Cell*. Inside the `CellTemplate` you define which property this template is for using `@context.Item.YourProperty`.

In the example below, for the `Elements.Number` property i've added a tooltip to the header only. So when you hover over the header you will see a tooltip.

I've added another example for the `Elements.Name` property where here it will display a tooltip for each cell.

```
<MudDataGrid Items="@Elements.Take(4)">
    <Columns>
        <TemplateColumn>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <MudTooltip Text="Only header tooltip" Color="Color.Secondary" Placement="Placement.Top">
                    Header template title for Number 
                </MudTooltip>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <CellTemplate>
                @context.Item.Number
            </CellTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Sign" />
        <TemplateColumn>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Header template title for Name
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <CellTemplate>
                <MudTooltip Text="Tooltip for each cell" Color="Color.Primary" Placement="Placement.Right">
                    @context.Item.Name
                </MudTooltip>
            </CellTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Position" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Molar" Title="Molar mass" />
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>
```

[image: HeaderTooltip]
[image: CellTooltip]

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOQdFuuZKFuflxre)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It worked for me.

Comment: @ashishrathore NP! can you please mark ✔ this as the answer.